# APEX testing a List variable

Tags: apex, soql

I am currently looking at more tests in Salesforce - I have made a new lightning app(just an expense application) and I am now just going through my controller and writing tests for it.
I have been okay so far but I have come across a List - literally just a list, and I have no idea how to test the lines of code I was wondering if you guys/gals could help me :)

Here's my method:

```
public static List<Expense__c> getExpenses() {     
    return [SELECT Id, Name, Amount__c, Client__c, Date__c,
    Reimbursed__c, CreatedDate FROM Expense__c];
}
```

Comment: You should probably have a `WHERE` clause on your query. This is really basic, I would look at some Trailhead lessons (e.g. [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_database/apex_database_soql)) if you are struggling.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create test data for it.

Create a Expense__c data.

```
public static testMethod void testmyExtension() {
       Expense__c exp = New Expense__c();
    exp.Name = 'Test';
    exp.Amount__c = 50;
    insert exp;

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(exp);
    //Your controller name
    myExtension e = new myExtension(sc);
   System.assertEquals(1,e.getExpenses.size());
}
```

Now your query will return 1 record and it will be covered.

Comment: I've just done this(I added on some more fields because some are required) but however this doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: Are you invoking your visualforce page and controller in test class ?

Comment: No I haven't I don't actually know how too, sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Please look into updated question.

Comment: assert should be `System.assertEquals(1,e.getExpenses.size());`